# How to persistently start a redmine server

Tags: redmine

I installed and started a redmine server on a linux machine, following the instructions at http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall and was wondering how I start the server in a way so that it won't stop when I log out of the ssh session.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways. The easiest way is to install a `screen` program and to run webrick in your screen session. Screen sessions are persistent, so you will be able to detach from the screen session and disconnect. This way is not optimal because webrick serve requests serially, so the performance is not too high. Second way is to install Apache and Phusion Passenger and to deploy Redmine on Passenger. This requires some amount of work. I can't find a Howto I used for that, but some details can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redmine_setup#Apache_w.2F_Phusion_Passenger), probably you will need to adapt this Howto to your distro.

Comment: I did exactly this not to long ago.  Even worked, eventually.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for the answer. Now how do I install redmine on apache on phusion passenger?

Answer (score 1):

You should **never ever** use `script/server` for production deployments. Use it only for testing and development. There are special application server (like [Passenger](http://modrails.com) which are suitable for actual deployments.

There are various HowTos on Google. But generally, Redmine deployments follow the default path documented in [Passenger's own documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application).

Answer (score 0):

you mean when you run this command?

> ruby script/server webrick -e
>   production

You can stick an ampersand '&' on the end of any command so that I'll background the process. i.e

> ruby script/server webrick -e
>   production &

for more information on backgrounding tasks, its worthwhile reading something [like this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/unix-background-job/).

As the documentation you've pointed to suggests you shouldn't be running with the webrick server for production.  You should look at installing  redmine with apache.

Comment: That runs the process in the background, but it will still exit once my connection is closed, right?

Comment: no it'll keep running & you can bring it back with fg

Answer (score 0):

nohup is what you use when you want to prevent it from die when exiting the shell.

I do agree with others that running the scripts like that might not be optimal.